# How to plot surfaces in the same graph with different colors?

Tags: plotting

I have ListPlot3D's which corresponds to one of 24 surfaces. Since I want to see the effect of change in parameters that shown in every surface, I want to plot these 24 surfaces in one graph but with different colors with also different labels. How can I do that?

This is my sample (2 surfaces) code:

```
xtime1 = {{8515.172419083505, 8515.172419083057, 8515.172419082499, 8515.17241908209, 8515.172419081428, 8515.172419080951, 8515.172419080476, 8515.172419079952, 
     8515.172419079467, 8515.172419078972, 8515.172419078604}, {9366.68966092754, 9366.689660863265, 9366.689660798713, 9366.689660734246, 9366.689660670076, 
     9366.689660605605, 9366.689660541118, 9366.689660476724, 9366.689660412287, 9366.689660347969, 9366.68966028363}, 
    {10218.206892766451, 10218.206887699582, 10218.206882632945, 10218.206877566105, 10218.206872499166, 10218.206867432376, 10218.20686236543, 10218.206857298796, 
     10218.206852231868, 10218.206847164998, 10218.206842098141}, {11069.72340697668, 11069.72316103375, 11069.722915091466, 11069.722669149676, 
     11069.722423208026, 11069.722177267282, 11069.721931327036, 11069.721685387429, 11069.721439447938, 11069.721193509278, 11069.720947571022}, 
    {11921.21180547675, 11921.204411183342, 11921.197017296367, 11921.189623815857, 11921.182230741704, 11921.174838074008, 11921.16744581267, 11921.1600539575, 
     11921.152662508384, 11921.145271465783, 11921.137880829066}, {12772.067467862695, 12771.929597678101, 12771.791847609327, 12771.654217426412, 
     12771.516706899762, 12771.379315800617, 12771.242043901257, 12771.104890973762, 12770.967856791916, 12770.830941129721, 12770.694143761424}, 
    {13614.750155093725, 13613.207529177631, 13611.67716279349, 13610.158846055578, 13608.652374643507, 13607.157549602198, 13605.67417715123, 13604.202068502762, 
     13602.741039687775, 13601.290911388509, 13599.851508780663}, {14403.051273071842, 14394.218073963495, 14385.687335452832, 14377.43797869228, 
     14369.451112274077, 14361.7097348923, 14354.198487395346, 14346.903444626232, 14339.811939572233, 14332.912413942522, 14326.19429051323}, 
    {15039.961771752312, 15016.919049292968, 14995.381502669063, 14975.162567416077, 14956.10863016614, 14938.091655910168, 14921.003776461459, 14904.753243822732, 
     14889.261353967608, 14874.460073754082, 14860.290185999724}, {15498.381096302599, 15462.470571878843, 15429.447807190993, 15398.8916223735, 
     15370.466227817604, 15343.899656258192, 15318.968591394469, 15295.487445803286, 15273.30033684588, 15252.27508510828, 15232.298653500471}, 
    {15829.310080582787, 15784.697281763523, 15743.89217948242, 15706.31987543982, 15671.524648699615, 15639.139409275103, 15608.864297295146, 15580.451340142008, 
     15553.693227717964, 15528.414951891787, 15504.467478868966}}; 

l1 = ListPlot3D[xtime1, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]; 

xtime2 = {{7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 
     7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892, 7769.719016091892}, {8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 
     8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839, 8546.690909887839}, 
    {9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 
     9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788, 9323.66241064788}, {10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 
     10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763, 10100.62101732763}, 
    {10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 
     10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272, 10877.306869048272}, {11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 
     11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 11650.317748777798, 
     11650.317748777798}, {12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 
     12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438, 12394.203758134438}, 
    {13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 
     13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785, 13029.240468915785}, {13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 
     13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 13497.236827867404, 
     13497.236827867404}, {13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 
     13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791, 13831.813174764791}, 
    {14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 
     14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636, 14082.087394806636}}; 

l2 = ListPlot3D[xtime2, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]; 

Show[l1, l2, PlotRange -> All];
```

Can you help me please to solve my problem? I hope you can understand my problem. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Why not show your code for the 3-surfaces? Most likely a small change to this will allow any number of colors.

Comment: There's no reason why this can't be done. You either missed something or made a syntax error, without seeing code, there's no way to know.

Comment: For instance: `ListPlot3D[
 Table[a - Sin[x y], {a, Range[0, 1.2, 0.2]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 
   3, 0.1}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Yellow, Red, Blue, Orange, Black, Purple}]`

Comment: I'm now editing my question

Comment: So, the example you gave is only for one table I guess, but I want to plot 24 table in the same graph.

Comment: tried joining different table?   ListPlot3D[
 Join[Table[
   a - Sin[x y], {a, Range[0, 1.2, 0.2]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 
    0.1}], Table[
   a + Sin[x y], {a, Range[0, 1.2, 0.2]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 
    0.1}]], PlotStyle -> {Green, Yellow, Red, Blue, Orange, Black, 
   Purple}]

Comment: @ecco did you try my answer?

Comment: yes, I tried. It works, thank you!

Comment: But works for 10 colors only. Any way to differentiate those 24 surfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) and [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

```
data = Join[{xtime1}, {xtime2}];
ListPlot3D[data, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Another option is [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)

```
Animate[ListPlot3D[data[[i]], DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z/Max[xtime2]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {i, 1, 2, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works again but just for 10 colors I think. Can I just increase the color range or show surfaces with different styles? I have to differentiate them.

Comment: @ecco `PlotLegends -> Range[24]`

Comment: and `PlotStyle -> Table[ColorData[97, c], {c, 1, 24}]`

Answer (score 2):

### Example

```
legend = SwatchLegend[
       {Red, Blue}, 
       {"Data Set 1" , "Data Set 2"},
       LegendMargins -> 5
       LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &)
   ];

ListPlot3D[{xtime1, xtime2}, PlotLegends -> legend]
```

### Alternatively

```
ListPlot3D[{xtime1, xtime2}, PlotLegends -> {"Data Set 1", "Data Set 2"}]
```

### Output

[image: output]
[image: output 2]

### Reference

[ListPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html)
[PlotLegends](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

Comment: You are welcome, hope it was of any use :)